# How to use wildcards in Windows Powershell V2.0

Tags: powershell, wildcard

I'm trying to do a simple copy with rename from the Powershell V2.0 command line as follows:

```
Copy-Item my_file.* my_file_old.*
```

I expect this to function the same as the DOS equivalent

```
copy my_file.* my_file_old.*
```

However, it's failing with the complaint "illegal characters in path". If I replace the wildcard `*` with a specific file number, e.g. 1, it works fine.

I guess I'm basically trying to replicate that DOS version but in Powershell, where I'd like to use the `-Exclude` parameter once I get this basic version sorted out.

What am I doing wrong? Some posts on another forum I found suggested wildcards were not supported in V2.0, but I can't believe that. That's like Microsoft saying "We just released a new version of Windows, but forgot to support keyboards and mice".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the help on `Copy-Item` it will tell you which parameters support wildcards and which do not.  `-Destination` does not support wildcards:

> -Destination 
>         Specifies the path to the new location. To rename a copied item, include the new name in the value.
>
> ```
>   Required?                    false
>   Position?                    2
>   Default value
>   Accept pipeline input?       true (ByPropertyName)
>   Accept wildcard characters?  false
> ```

You can do what you want it with a tiny bit of script:

```
Get-ChildItem my_file.* | Copy-Item -Dest {$_.basename + "_old" + $_.extension} -WhatIf
```

Remove the `-WhatIf` parameter when you are happy it will copy the files correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Wildcards are definitely supported, assuming you use them properly. A wildcard in your destination is strange and in most situations not what you want. And copying a file (or group of files) onto itself (which is what you're doing here - when you don't specify parameter names for `Copy-Item` the first is the source and the second is the destination) is almost certainly not what you want.

```
copy-item myFile.* -destination DESTPATH
```

or

```
get-childitem -filter myFile.* | Copy-Item -destination DESTPATH
```

Comment: Sorry, I realized I made the example in a bit of a hurry, and left out an edit to the second file name. I've clarified my question above. I'm not trying to copy the files onto themselves, but rather into the same folder with modified names but the same extensions (which are sequential numbers in my case) maintained. Please see updated question.

Comment: To clarify, working off your second example, I would be trying to do something like `get-childitem -filter my_file.* | Copy-Item -destination my_file_old.*`, and when I look at it in pipeline form, I'm wondering if I actually need a loop of some kind to run through the filenames and copy with renaming.

Comment: This is *very* relevant information which should have been in your original post (I replied pre-edit). Yes, you're going to need a `foreach-object` in the pipeline to copy the files to the same directory with new names (or rename them in-place).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of renaming a bunch of .jpg files to a sequential list of numbers [001.jpg, 002.jpg, etc]

```
get-childitem *.jpg | foreach-object -begin {$count=1} -process {rename-item -path $_.FullName -newname ('{0:000}.jpg' -f $count++)}
```

You could adapt this to meet your needs by adjusting the *.jpg and '{0:000}.jpg' parts